# Is adding a value inside an array.map considered mutating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I know redux is strict with state management, but is adding a value from an array of objects considered a no no in redux? Example:

```js
// Consider this array of objects on action
action.arr = [ { test: 'me', hail: 'hydra'}, { test: 'you', ring: 'of fire'} ]
// reducer.js
fn = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  ...
  case action.LORD_COMMANDER:
    return action.arr.map(v => {
      v.john = 'snow'
      return v
    })
  ...
}
```

Is this completely safe on my reducer or should I use `Object.assign()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think better use `Object.assign`. Let's consider two examples

```js
const arr  = [ { test: 'me', hail: 'hydra'}, { test: 'you', ring: 'of fire'} ];
const arr1 = arr.map(v => {
  v.john = 'snow'
  return v;
});

console.log(arr, arr1);
```

As you can see each `Object` in two arrays have property `john` because we change *Objects* which have same reference that is not safe for previous `Array`., in example below you can see that only in second `Array` Objects have property `john` it is because we make copy of `Object`

```js
const arr  = [ { test: 'me', hail: 'hydra'}, { test: 'you', ring: 'of fire'} ];
const arr1 = arr.map(v => {
  return Object.assign({}, v, { john: 'show' })
});

console.log(arr, arr1);
```

Comment: Nice example. Forgot javascript is pass by reference

Answer (score 1):

in this case you are making your state to be the array and since the array in the action is always going to be different then yes you are mutating the state. as long as the objects are not references the state will be completely mutated a sample of a dirty state is.

`var objA = {};
var objB = {};
action.array = [objA, objB];`

in this case when you do the map your reference to the array would be new but the reference to the objects would be the same. here it would be advised to use Object.assign or (...) operator inside of your map function. or better yet i would recommend looking into immutablejs to handle immutable data

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Comment: Sorry mate I like Alexander's answer better. But here take my upvote! :) And for immutable. I find it tiresome to use. So I'll stick with plain ol' javascript.

Comment: the advantage of immutable is that when used properly (fromJS/withMutations) no matter how nested your data is you can always guarantee an immutable state. in those cases object.assign or deconstruction wont be of help. Thx for the upvote. appreciated